# Translation of "I am concerned that (it) could be difficult"

Tags: subjonctif

According to Google translate, the phrase:

> "I am concerned that it could be difficult."

is translated as:

> "Je crains que cela puisse être difficile."

Which seems like a fairly direct translation, although "craindre" feels a bit strong.

But if I change the sentence slightly to:

> "I am concerned that the installation could be difficult."

I get:

> "Je crains que l'installation ne soit difficile."

To my English brain, the "ne" in there doesn't look right.

Are these two forms really semantically equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Craindre* is certainly usable (although [some](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45483/translation-of-i-am-concerned-that-it-could-be-difficult/45486?noredirect=1#comment92644_45486) might consider *craindre* to be a little too formal here):

> *Je crains que ce soit difficile.*

and you can also use the more mainstream *avoir peur*:

> *J'ai peur que ce soit difficile.*

The translation you got is also perfectly idiomatic although slightly more formal:

> *Je crains que l'installation ne soit difficile.*

You are bothered by the *ne* because it's a *ne expletif* that doesn't convey any negative meaning. In casual spoken French, you usually drop it:

> J'ai peur que l'installation soit difficile.

Another way to express the concern is:

> *Je me fais du souci à propos de l'installation.*

Comment: I would add that "Je crains que ce soit difficile" sounds a bit wrong to me, although it might technically be correct, and would more naturally be "Je crains que ce ne soit difficile".

Comment: @Stef That's true if you are writing a book or something but as far as spoken French is concerned, the version with *ne* is highly formal while the version without it is standard. I wouldn't call "a bit wrong" the mainstream usage.

Comment: I would argue that this usage of the verb "craindre" is formal enough that anyone actually using it would use "ne" as well, even in casual conversation.

Comment: @Stef I understand what you mean but I wouldn't call a dialog containing *que ce ne soit* a "casual conversation", it's quite formal to my ears. *Craindre* formality can vary with the region or the context (*Il craint les chatouilles*, *Ça craint* and *On craint dégun* are informal)

Answer (score 1):

**I** I think I can rally to the point of view that "craindre" is a  formulation somewhat too strong, specially as "concerned (that)" means "worried". Instead of this construction something along the line of the following might be preferable.

- Je me soucie du fait que cela pourrait être difficile. (*less strong*)
- J'ai dans l'idée que cela pourrait être difficile. (*still less strong*)

**II** This particle is called "ne explétif", which means that it conveys no meaning; it can be removed without changing anything.

> (LBU 14ième édition § 1023) Lorsque le locuteur sent dans le contexte une idée de négation, il
> introduit parfois dans les propositions conjonctives  un *ne* que l'on
> appelle explétif, à la fois parce qu'il peut toujours être omis et parce qu'il
> ne correspond pas à une négation objective.  Ce *ne* est donc facultatif,
> même si les grammairiens ont essayé de rendre son emploi plus rigide.
>
> - *Je crains qu'on NE me trompe* (La pensée s'arrête sur
>   l'idée de n'être pas trompé.)
>
> *Translation by user LPH* When the speaker becomes aware of an idea of negation in the context, he/she introduces sometimes in conjunctive clauses un *ne* that can be called "explétif", so called both because it can always be omitted and because it corresponds to no real negation. Therefore, this *ne* is optional, even though grammarians have tried in the past to make its usage more strict.
>
> - *Je crains qu'on NE me trompe* (The speaker's thinking focuses on the idea of not being cheated.)

It follows that this sentence has the same meaning as the following.

- Je crains que l'installation  soit difficile.